# How to enqueue custom python class in pyres?

Tags: python, jobs

So i'm trying to get pyres to work; to get my custom class to run a simple perform which simply prints hello to the screen.
here is my job class

```
class Foobar:
    queue = "Spam"
    def perform(self, number):
        print 'hi'
```

Then after running my redis server via `redis-server`

ill go into python env and run the following

```
from pyres import *
r = ResQ(server="192.168.1.10:6379", password="")
import Foobar
r.enqueue(Foobar, 5)
from pyres.worker import Worker
Worker.run(['Spam'], server="localhost:6379")
```

I should expect a simple hello when I execute my worker, however nothing prints to the python environment.  Help is appreciated as I noticed the community is not so large around pyres and the documentation is too contrived

In addition i downloaded ruby resque gem to monitor my workers via `resque-web` command and it seems the worker "Spam" is ready but the job never enqueues.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding @staticmethod on your perform method

See the pyres documentation example: http://itybits.com/pyres/example.html

In your case, a complete example would be:

```
class Foobar:
    queue = "Spam"
    @staticmethod
    def perform(number):
        print 'hi'

from pyres import ResQ
r = ResQ(server="localhost:6379", password="")
r.enqueue(Foobar, 5)
from pyres.worker import Worker
Worker.run(['Spam'], server="127.0.0.1:6379")
```

Answer (score -1):

My issue is that you are unable to pass self within the perform method since pyres looks for the perform method along with any args you pass it. By modifying the perform method to become static, the class is now enqueue-able and can be executed by the worker.  In addition, if you have another function within the same class, you would need to declare those as static as well if you are calling it within the class. My full Job class is replicated below

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pyres import ResQ

client = MongoClient()

db = client['trending']

class FacebookSocial:
    queue = "FacebookSocial"

   @staticmethod
   def perform():
       articles = FacebookSocial.get_urls()
       for article in articles:
            fbsocial = FacebookSocial.get_social(article)

   @staticmethod
   def get_urls():
       articles = db.articles.find()
       return articles

  @staticmethod
  def get_social(article):
      fbsocial += article
      return fbsocial


r = ResQ()
r.enqueue(FacebookSocial)
```